Verifying the Distribution of a Standardized Least Squares Estimator in Simple Linear Regression
I have the following linear regression,
$$
Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+\epsilon_i
$$
where $\epsilon_i^{\prime}$ s are independent $N\left(0, \sigma^2\right)$ random variables. Let $\hat{\beta}_i$ denote the (ordinary) least square estimators of parameters for $i=0,1$.
I am wondering the distribution of
$$
\frac{\hat{\beta}_0-\beta_0}{\sqrt{s^2\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar{x}^2}{s_{x x}}\right)}}
$$
where $s^2=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(s_{y y}-\frac{s_{x y}^2}{s_{x x}}\right)$. I thought as the following: Under the assumptions of the simple linear regression model and normality of errors, the standardized estimator $Z$ follows a $t$-distribution with ( $\mathbf{n}-2$ ) tiers of freedom.
Reason:

$\hat{\beta}_0$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the normally distributed variables $Y_i$.
$\mathrm{S}^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.
The denominator represents the standard mistakes of $\hat{\beta_0 }$

Is the reasoning true, or how can I make it more rigorous?
